# What are the core directives in AngularJS framwork?

Tags: angularjs

There are many directives exist in **AngularJS** framework but among them which are considered to be set of **core directives** among others directives of the framework. 
Thanks

Comment: What does "core directives" means for you?

Comment: I mean those directives that must be needed to stat a Angular JS application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**AngularJS's directives**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) just provide you a way to **extend HTML** with new attributes. So you can use Angular's set of built-in directives (maybe what you called "core directives?") as you want, or write your owns.

---

If I understand well your question, you are asking if the use of directives is **required** to make an AngularJS app.

The answer is no. Directives are are just there to help you write your code easier, more efficiently and clearly.

However, you will use them (very) often...